# Why can't I connect Wordpress to mySQL Server?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read through all documentation and searched the internet for hours but I just can't figure out my issue. I have my files in my public_html folder and when I go through the WordPress setup it always gives me this error when I go to connect to my database.

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'a7977118_long'@'10.1.1.31' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a7977118/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1515

I found the line of code giving me problems if its any help. Thank you in advance!

```
if ( $this->dbh->connect_errno ) {
            $this->dbh = null;

            /* It's possible ext/mysqli is misconfigured. Fall back to ext/mysql if:
             *  - We haven't previously connected, and
             *  - WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL isn't set to false, and
             *  - ext/mysql is loaded.
             */
            $attempt_fallback = true;

            if ( $this->has_connected ) {
                $attempt_fallback = false;
            } elseif ( defined( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL' ) && ! WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL ) {
                $attempt_fallback = false;
            } elseif ( ! function_exists( 'mysql_connect' ) ) {
                $attempt_fallback = false;
            }

            if ( $attempt_fallback ) {
                $this->use_mysqli = false;
                return $this->db_connect( $allow_bail );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
    }

    if ( ! $this->dbh && $allow_bail ) {
        wp_load_translations_early();

        // Load custom DB error template, if present.
        if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db-error.php' ) ) {
            require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db-error.php' );
            die();
        }
```

Comment: You are most probably using 000webhost, which has a delay in setting up new databases. It might be a case that your database wasn't setup yet, just need to wait longer for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear here that the user (**a7977118_long**) you are providing during the set up doesn't have required permissions to the database you are connecting to.

The usual procedure is to set up the database.

1. Create the database
2. Create a user and assign a password to it.
3. Run Wordpress setup
4. Provide correct `database name, username, password` as setup in steps 1 & 2 above during the installation.